# Coroutines: runBlocking vs coroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was reading [Coroutine Basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html) trying to understand and learn it.

There is a part there with this code:

```
fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }

    coroutineScope { // Creates a new coroutine scope
        launch {
            delay(900L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }

        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before nested launch
    }

    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until nested launch completes
}
```

The output goes like so:

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
Coroutine scope is over
```

My question is why this line:

```
 println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until nested launch completes
```

is called always last?

Shouldn't it be called since the:

```
coroutineScope { // Creates a new coroutine scope
    ....
}
```

is suspended?

There is also a note there:

> The main difference between runBlocking and coroutineScope is that the latter does not block the current thread while waiting for all children to complete.

I dont understand how coroutineScope and runBlocking are different here? coroutineScope looks like its blocking since it only gets to the last line when it is done.

Can anyone enlighten me here?

Comment: you may also find the documentation about [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) insightful....

Comment: The docs should be updated to better explain this because you are not the only one who has interpreted it this way.

Comment: Kotlin has such an awful documentation, keep throwing concepts out of nowhere, and confusing explanation.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

> I don't understand how coroutineScope and runBlocking are different here? coroutineScope looks like its blocking since it only gets to the last line when it is done.

There are two separate worlds: the *suspendable* world (within a coroutine) and the *non-suspendable* one. As soon as you enter the body of `runBlocking`, you are in the suspendable world, where `suspend fun`s behave like blocking code and you can't get to the next line until the `suspend fun` returns. `coroutineScope` is a `suspend fun` that returns only when all the coroutines inside it are done. Therefore the last line must print at the end.

---

*I copied the above explanation from a comment which seems to have clicked with readers. Here is the original answer:*

From the perspective of the code in the block, your understanding is correct. The difference between `runBlocking` and `coroutineScope` happens at a lower level: what's happening to the thread while the coroutine is blocked?

- `runBlocking` is not a `suspend fun`. The thread that called it remains inside it until the coroutine is complete.
- `coroutineScope` is a `suspend fun`. If your coroutine suspends, the `coroutineScope` function gets suspended as well. This allows the top-level function, a *non-suspending* function that created the coroutine, to continue executing on the same thread. The thread has "escaped" the `coroutineScope` block and is ready to do some other work.

In your specific example: when your `coroutineScope` suspends, control returns to the implementation code inside `runBlocking`. This code is an event loop that drives all the coroutines you started within it. In your case, there will be some coroutines scheduled to run after a delay. When the time arrives, it will resume the appropriate coroutine, which will run for a short while, suspend, and then control will be again inside `runBlocking`.

---

While the above describes the conceptual similarities, it should also show you that `runBlocking` is a *completely different* tool from `coroutineScope`.

- `runBlocking` is a low-level construct, to be used only in framework code or self-contained examples like yours. It turns an existing thread into an event loop and creates its coroutine with a `Dispatcher` that posts resuming coroutines to the event loop's queue.
- `coroutineScope` is a user-facing construct, used to delineate the boundaries of a task that is being parallel-decomposed inside it. You use it to conveniently await on all the `async` work happening inside it, get the final result, and handle all failures at one central place.

Comment: Is it just because of the 'runBlocking' that the last line gets called after the coroutineScope finished?

Comment: No. The two separate worlds are the _suspendable_ world (within a coroutine) and the _non-suspendable_ one. As soon as you enter the body of `runBlocking`, you are in the suspendable world, where `suspend fun`s behave like blocking code and you can't get to the next line until the `suspend fun` returns. `coroutineScope` is a `suspend fun` that returns only when all the coroutines inside it are done. Therefore the last line must print at the end.

Comment: I finally get it! Thank you very much! I was confusing 'CoroutineScope' with 'coroutineScope'. Now i unserstand they are two different things. 'CoroutineScope' launches a coroutine while 'coroutineScope' is a suspending function which bridges building of coroutines and suspending function :) Thank you soo much :)

Comment: `CoroutineScope` is just a holder of a `CoroutineContext`, that's all it is. `launch`, `async` and others are extension funs on `CoroutineScope` and they simply fetch its context, combine it with any context you additionally supplied in the argument, and the result is the context of the coroutine you're building.

Comment: Great answer! One thing I may ask is about this line `"to continue executing on the same thread"`. Does it have to be the same thread to continue execution?

Comment: @stdout That sentence talks about the lower-level mechanism. The thing that continues execution is top-level event loop code and not any coroutine. Then that code will select another coroutine dispatched to the same thread and resume it.

Answer (score 52):

The chosen answer is good but fails to address some other important aspects of the sample code that was provided. For instance, launch is non-blocking and is suppose to execute immediately. That is simply not true. The launch itself returns immediately BUT the code inside the launch does appear to be put into a queue and is only executed when any other launches that were previously put into the queue have completed.

Here's a similar piece of sample code with all the delays removed and an additional launch included. Without looking at the result below, see if you can predict the order in which the numbers are printed. Chances are that you will fail:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch { 
        println("1")
    }

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            println("2")
        }

        println("3") 
    }

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            println("4")
        }

        println("5")
    }

    launch { 
        println("6")
    }

    for (i in 7..100) {
        println(i.toString())
    }

    println("101")
}
```

The result is:

```
3
1
2
5
4
7
8
9
10
...
99
100
101
6
```

The fact that number 6 is printed last, even after going through nearly 100 println have been executed, indicates that the code inside the last launch never gets executed until all non-blocking code after the launch has completed. But that is not really true either, because if that were the case, the first launch should not have executed until numbers 7 to 101 have completed. Bottom line? Mixing launch and coroutineScope is highly unpredictable and should be avoided if you expect a certain order in the way things should be executed.

To prove that code inside launches is placed into a queue and ONLY executed after ALL the non-blocking code has completed, run this (no coroutineScopes are used):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch { 
        println("1")
    }

    launch { 
        println("2")
    }

    launch { 
        println("3")
    }

    for (i in 4..100) {
        println(i.toString())
    }

    println("101")
}
```

This is the result you get:

```
4
5
6
...
101
1
2
3
```

Adding a CoroutineScope will break this behavior. It will cause all non-blocking code that follows the CoroutineScope to not be executed until ALL code prior to the CoroutineScope has completed.

It should also be noted that in this code sample, each of the launches in the queue are executed sequentially in the order that they are added to the queue and each launch will only execute AFTER the previous launch executes. This may make it appear that all launches share a common thread. This is not true. Each of them is given their own thread. However, if any code inside a launch calls a suspend function, the next launch in the queue is started immediately while the suspend function is being carried out. To be honest, this is very strange behavior. Why not just run all the launches in the queue asynchronously? While I don't know the internals of what goes on in this queue, my guess is that each launch in the queue does not get its own thread but all share a common thread. It is only when a suspend function is encountered does it appear that a new thread is created for the next launch in the queue. It may be done this way to save on resources.

To summarize, execution is done in this order:

1. Code inside a launch is placed inside a queue and are executed in the order that they are added.
2. Non-blocking code following a launch executes immediately before anything in the queue is executed.
3. A CoroutineScope blocks ALL code following it BUT will execute all the launch coroutines in the queue before resuming to the code following the CoroutineScope.

Comment: for one, there is a difference between `CoroutineScope` and `coroutineScope` so be more careful about that.

Comment: sthe reason why `coroutineScope` "blocks" the code following it is because `coroutineScope` is a suspending function. `coroutineScope` suspends until all couroutines/functions have return. Its basically a "scoping" mechanism.

Comment: non-blocking code (`launch`) returns immediately that is why the code next to it is executed immediately.

Comment: I am not sure about this but I believe there is no concept of "queue" in coroutines. If coroutines are handled in a "queue" it should not be possible to have the second launched coroutine with no delay do its thing first over the first luanch coroutine with a 2 seconds delay.

Comment: Overall though I think the explaination is quite good so ill still upvote it.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Whether a queue is used internally or not isn't important. It certainly acts like one. To test this, just run to launches, one after the other, and have them both do a significant amount of work. The second launch will not start executing its code until the first one completes. Add a third launch and it will not start until the second one completes. But as already mentioned, this behavior is changed the moment some code in a coroutine calls a suspend function.

Comment: The docs also state: "Note that concurrency with coroutines is always explicit." - meaning that they are executed sequentially, unless you explicitly request that they be executed asynchronously - hence the concept of a "queue".

Comment: I really have an issue with thinking of coroutines as a queue. It actually works more like a stack internally.

Comment: `The second launch will not start executing its code until the first one completes` --- this is just an artifact of using a single-threaded coroutine dispatcher and does not belong to the semantics of coroutines. The semantics are "concurrent execution that starts immediately when you call `launch`", and the rest is up to the internal scheduling.

Comment: As a beginner, this is mind-bending.. :(

Comment: I was pretty confused by this but indeed @MarkoTopolnik is right... if you change this to `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default)` you'll get a totally different result, and it'll be different every time.

Answer (score 13):

Well, after having read all the answers here, I found none of them answered the question beyond repeating the wording of the fragments of the documentation.

So, I went on to search for an answer elsewhere and found it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_xRxXoimSw). It practically shows the difference in behavior of `coroutineScope` and `runBlocking` (i.e. the difference between suspending and blocking)

Comment: The only net effect is that coroutineScope can be cancelled. That's it.

Answer (score 8):

`runBlocking` just **blocks** the current thread until inner coroutines will be completed. Here, thread that executes `runBlocking` will be **blocked until** the coroutine from `coroutineScope` will be finished.

First `launch` just won't allow the thread execute instructions that come after `runBlocking`, but will allow proceed to the instructions that come immediately after this `launch` block - that's why `Task from coroutine scope` is printed before than `Task from runBlocking`.

But nested `coroutineScope` in the context of `runBlocking` won't allow the thread to execute instructions that come after this `coroutineScope` block, because `runBlocking` will block the thread until the coroutine from `coroutineScope` will  be finished completely. And that's why `Coroutine scope is over` will always come after `Task from nested launch`.

Answer (score 3):

From this wonderful article https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/05/04/parallel-map-in-kotlin/

```
suspend fun <A, B> Iterable<A>.pmap(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = coroutineScope {
    map { async { f(it) } }.awaitAll()
}
```

> With runBlocking, we were not using Structured Concurrency, so an invocation of f could fail and all other executions would continue unfazed. And also we were not playing nice with the rest of the code. By using runBlocking we were forcefully blocking the thread until the whole execution of pmap finishes, instead of letting the caller decide how the execution should go.

Answer (score 1):

Your question about why `println("Coroutine scope is over")` called always last is not relevant about the difference between runBlocking vs coroutineScope.
The accepted answer only explains the the difference between runBlocking vs coroutineScope. I will try to explain the other one.

First, I guess you misrepresent `coroutineScope` and `launch`.

1. `coroutineScope` is a suspend function, it will suspend and not resume until all codes inside it are finished.
2. `launch` is a normal function, it run suspend actions **concurrently**.

So the codes inside `coroutineScope`, two `println` will run in parallel.

```
coroutineScope { // Creates a new coroutine scope
    launch {
        delay(900L) 
        println("Task from nested launch")
    }

    delay(100L)
    println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before nested launch
}
```

And with delay actions, the second one will be run first.

What bothering you is here. Why the first `println` run, but the last one don't?

```
fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }

    coroutineScope { // Creates a new coroutine scope
        launch {
            delay(900L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }

        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before nested launch
    }

    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until nested launch completes
}
```

Because `launch` is a normal function, and `coroutineScope` is a suspend function. So the first `println` will not be blocked.
If you change the `launch` to `coroutineScope`, the second `coroutineScope` will be blocked until the first one is resumed and return.

---

I think the difficultity of kotlin coroutine is that:

1. there are several terms are hard to understand.
2. apis in lambda style hide many details, it is easy to use but lose calling context about where you are.

Answer (score 0):

```
suspend fun A() {
        Log.d("Test", "suspend A started")
        delay(5000)
        Log.d("Test", "suspend A over")
    }

    suspend fun B() {
        Log.d("Test", "suspend B")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("Test", "suspend B over")
    }

    suspend fun D() {
        Log.d("Test", "suspend D")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("Test", "suspend D over")
    }

    suspend fun E() {
        Log.d("Test", "suspend E")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("Test", "suspend E over")
    }
```

```
fun main3() {
        runBlocking {
            // suspend = async + await = launch + join
            // suspend != async (async runs and returns when it has)
            // all launch will run parallel
    
            launch{
                A()
            }.join()
            
            launch{
                D()
            }

            launch {
                E()
            }

            async { // Extension of a coroutine Scope not its own scope
                Log.d("Test", "async C started")
                delay(1000)
                Log.d("Test", "async C over")
            }.await()

            launch{
                B()
            }
        }
        Log.d("Test", "main3 over")
    }
```

Result:

```
2024-02-16 17:39:16.759  suspend A started
2024-02-16 17:39:21.760  suspend A over
2024-02-16 17:39:21.762  suspend D
2024-02-16 17:39:21.762  suspend E
2024-02-16 17:39:21.762  async C started
2024-02-16 17:39:22.762  suspend D over
2024-02-16 17:39:22.762  suspend E over
2024-02-16 17:39:22.762  async C over
2024-02-16 17:39:22.763  suspend B
2024-02-16 17:39:23.763  suspend B over
2024-02-16 17:39:23.764  main3 over
```

```
    fun main4() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            // suspend = async + await = launch + join
            // suspend != async (async runs and returns when it has)
            launch{
                A()
            }.join()

            launch{
                D()
            }

            launch {
                E()
            }

            async {  // Extension of a coroutine Scope not its own scope
                Log.d("Test", "async C started")
                delay(1000)
                Log.d("Test", "async C over")
            }.await()

            launch{
                B()
            }
        }
        Log.d("Test", "main4 over")
    }
```

Result:

```
2024-02-16 17:34:20.141  main4 over
2024-02-16 17:34:20.142  suspend A started
2024-02-16 17:34:25.144  suspend A over
2024-02-16 17:34:25.145  suspend D
2024-02-16 17:34:25.145  async C started
2024-02-16 17:34:25.145  suspend E
2024-02-16 17:34:26.146  suspend D over
2024-02-16 17:34:26.146  async C over
2024-02-16 17:34:26.146  suspend E over
2024-02-16 17:34:26.146  suspend B
2024-02-16 17:34:27.147  suspend B over
```