# CoroutineScope blocks current thread

Tags: kotlin

According to the Kotlin docs, a CoroutineScope does not block the current thread. They show this code example:

```
fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }

    coroutineScope { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            delay(500L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }

        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before the nested launch
    }

    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until the nested launch completes
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
Coroutine scope is over
```

They even include the comment:

> This line is not printed until the nested launch completes

And sure enough, that line doesn't print until the end. But this is what I don't understand. They say that the CoroutineScope does not block the current thread. So why doesn't this line print after the first launch is completed?:

```
println("Coroutine scope is over")
```

This line is not part of the coroutineScope. I would have expected the result to be:

```
Coroutine scope is over
Task from runBlocking
Task from coroutine scope
Task from nested launch
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coroutines: runBlocking vs coroutineScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535977/coroutines-runblocking-vs-coroutinescope)

Comment: Woah. Thanks a lot. Seems like others had the same issue with this.