# How to understand order of calling coroutines with scope?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I saw the coroutines example [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#scope-builder).

To understand the example I made three different examples with each scope.
The printed number is the following #N.
It's just my opinion, so if there is a wrong thing, let me know.

#1: 3->1->2->4

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        println("1-Task from runBlocking")
    }

    coroutineScope { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            println("2-Task from nested launch")
        }

        println("3-Task from coroutine scope")
    }

    println("4-Coroutine scope is over") 
}
```

I understood the `coroutineScope` waits until the children will be completed. The outer `runBlocking` has two coroutines.
The first is `launch` of `1` and the second is in `coroutineScope`.
The `coroutineScope` will be handled first based on the call stack.
Thus the first printed number is `3` because it's within regular function.
And then the `1` can be printed before `2`.
The `4` will be printed after `coroutineScope` block is finished.

#2: 1->3->2->4

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        println("1-Task from runBlocking")
    }

    runBlocking { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            println("2-Task from nested launch")
        }

        println("3-Task from coroutine scope")
    }

    println("4-Coroutine scope is over")
}
```

`runBlocking` is not suspend function that's why the outer `runBlocking` doesn't have a coroutine.
 Thus the `1` will be printed first. After that, the inner `runBlocking` has one coroutine so wait until this block will be finished.
 Thus `3` and `2` will be printed. Last, `4` printed after inner `runBlocking`.

#3: 2->4->3->1, 4->3->2->1, 4->2->3->1

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        println("1-Task from runBlocking")
    }

    GlobalScope.launch { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            println("2-Task from nested launch")
        }

        println("3-Task from coroutine scope")
    }

    println("4-Coroutine scope is over") 
}
```

There are several different results so I guessed it depends on environments on runtime.
But I wonder if it's impossible to print `1` first or not.
Second, how to understand scope in other `suspend` or `scope`.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/q/53535977/7298476