# Why does coroutineScope block the process?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In [this official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder), it says that coroutineScope just suspends, releasing the underlying thread for other usages.
But in example code, it looks it blocks the next process because `println("Coroutine scope is over")` is not executed until finishing the code block in coroutineScope.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }
    
    coroutineScope { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            delay(500L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
    
        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before the nested launch
    }
    
    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until the nested launch completes
}
```

I know runBlocking waits until all its children to complete. So in my understanding, runBlocking should wait for coroutineScope to complete after executing `println("Coroutine scope is over")` line.

Why does coroutineScope block the thread in this example?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535977/coroutines-runblocking-vs-coroutinescope/53536713#53536713) is a relevant post for your question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link.
The description in the link you shared is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

coroutineScope suspended CoroutineScope scope, so the line "println("Coroutine scope is over") " would be executed after the previous coroutineScope completed.
You can see the code of coroutineScope function :

```
public suspend fun <R> coroutineScope(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> R): R {
contract {
    callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
}
return suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn { uCont ->
    val coroutine = ScopeCoroutine(uCont.context, uCont)
    coroutine.startUndispatchedOrReturn(coroutine, block)
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could understand it!