# How to run CoroutineScope in RecyclerViewCursorAdapter on ViewHolder inside bindCursor{ }

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, simplecursoradapter

**Note: I had implemented Coroutine Single Scope in RecyclerViewCursorAdapter but the app getting too slow when I change it to runBlocking it's working fine**

Is there any way to execute CoroutineScope in ViewHolder inside bindCursor{ } on every scroll without impacting on performance ?
I need to execute multiple queries from the database on every scroll and update the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, there is a better way of doing what you are doing than to do it in adapter. I don't think that is correct, maybe you can use a callback via an interface or something.

But to return to your question, you should be easily be able to do this using `lifeCycleScope`

> A LifecycleScope is defined for each Lifecycle object. Any coroutine launched in this scope is canceled when the Lifecycle is destroyed.

Since you have not mentioned whether it is an activity or an fragment that you are using, but the logic and functionality remains same for both. I am going to give you an example for `Fragment`

```kotlin
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Just like that you can launch coroutines and it will be handled as per the lifecycle, you may need to pass the `viewLifeCycleOwner` to your Fragment, although as I said that is not recommended, you are better using an interface of sort and then computing in `Fragment` itself, but you can get the idea.

Comment: Actually, the whole project made on MVP pattern. I have Model, view, Presenter, and table helper classes, I am not able to use viewModelScope or lifecycleScope

Comment: `lifeCycleScope` is available in your activity and fragment.  I think you should be able to use that even with the MVP pattern. You do not need `ViewModel` for it.

Comment: RecyclerViewCursorAdapter initializing  on fragment but I have already mentioned  in question I need to use Coroutine scope in RecyclerViewCursorAdapter inside bindview on scroll

Comment: Pass the `viewLifeCycleOwner` to your Adapter when you are initializing it @DanishKhan. Again, not recommended, but you can do it.

Comment: I'm not much aware of viewLifeCycleOwner, could you give me an example. how to pass viewLifeCycleOwner  in RecyclerViewCursorAdapter if possible.

Comment: Can you post some code of our adapter @DanishKhan Just pass it via the constructor when you are initializing it and setting it. Also `viewLifeCycleOwner` is for Fragments, if you are using Activity, you need to pass the Activity itself.

Comment: I have attached the code.. could you check it
https://pl.kotl.in/nFCfmD9IH

Comment: Is it an Fragment or an activity @DanishKhan

Comment: It fragment but the adapter is initializing in Presenter

Comment: @DanishKhan The same way you are getting the context in your presenter, you need to get the LifeCycleOwner in it which is `viewLifeCycleOwner` in case of Fragments and then you can pass it as you are passing the context and other parameters in the adapter constructor.

Comment: val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(getView()!!.getActivityContext())
        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        skusAdapter = obStores?.let { SkusAdapter(getActivityContext(), this, mModel!!, it, SkusAdapter.ROW, lsp.showInventory, lsp.requiredImagesCount) }
        skusAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        recyclerView.adapter = skusAdapter

        when (type) {
            BookingOrderFragment.TYPE_BRAND -> getView()!!.filterList(bundle, OrderActivityNew.SKU_BRANDS_LOADER)
        
        }



//Adapter intilazing code mentioned above

Comment: Yes you need to pass it here only inside the SkusAdapter and then you can make use of it inside your adapter to launch a `lifeCycleScope`

Comment: how to pass viewLifeCycleOwner as a parameter ? could you show me the code

Comment: Yes, like this `private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner`, so your adapter will be something like this

`class SkusAdapter(private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, private val context: Context`

Comment: private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
Your mean Just declares this Object in fragment and passes as an argument in adapter but where to initialize LifecycleOwner ?

Comment: It is already initialized in your Fragment @DanishKhan. See the code that is in my answer you will get an idea.

Comment: Kindly correct me i am observing "private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner" this is just a declaration not initializing

Comment: Yes it is a declaration only @DanishKhan As I said it is already an initialized property in your Fragment. Just like there is context which you can access in your Fragment, you can access the `viewLifeCycleOwner` after `onViewCreated()`

Comment: i am not able to get viewLifeCycleOwner  in Activity. is there any way to pass it by activity

Comment: Use `this` instead for activity @DanishKhan and please mark this answer as correct if it helped you so other who maybe stumble upon this can use it too.

Comment: let me implement then revert you the conclusion

Comment: I passed it but how to use it without live data.

viewLifeCycleOwner.{
 var data = model.getDatafromSuspendFunction()
} 


I was considering this syntax

Comment: i don't have mvvm and live data

Comment: You don't need MVVM or Live Data, you just need lifecycle extensions to launch a coroutine scope that is scoped to the lifecycle so it automatically cancels when views are destroyed @DanishKhan 
Add the following in your gradle `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0` and that is all you need to do `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { }`

Comment: I have implemented the above solution but the app still performing the same as "Coroutine Single Scope" that I had mentioned in the question.  I even don't understand why runblocking{} working fast than viewLifecycleOwner and Coroutine Single Scope. Recycle list Items Ui is blinking on every scroll when I had to implement viewLifecycleOwner or CoroutineSingle Scope but when I change it to runBlocking{}  list UI working smoothly without blinking

Comment: @DanishKhan You might want to check this. Using `runBlocking` will have lot of repercussions. https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-deadlock-your-android-app-with-runblocking-8dab02c2624d

Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535977/coroutines-runblocking-vs-coroutinescope

Comment: I had read this article ... but still shocking when I do practical

Comment: Your call entirely. Maybe try using a different scope of Dispatchers like `Dispatcher.IO` which are made specifically for IO operations.

Comment: I am using a room lib with suspendinged fun there is no need to define Dispatcher. they suspend themselves into their own dispatcher defined in the Room library.