# Difference between MainCoroutineRule and runBlocking

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines

`MainCoroutineRule` and `runBlocking` of Kotlin Coroutines both are designed for testing purposes. And seems like both are offering the same functionality: running code synchronously in a test environment.
So what's the difference? What's the best use case for each of them?

Comment: here some one mention https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536713/10991969, hope it will help u. :)

Comment: @Skysoft13 Thanks but I'm talking about the `MainCoroutineRule`. It's a testing rule.

Comment: sorry, understand. :))

Comment: `runBlocking` is not designed for testing purposes only, it also serves many use cases of bridging blocking code with coroutine-based code (in production code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MainCoroutineRule` and `runBlocking` are seemingly similar but there are clear differences.

Defenition of [MainCoroutineRule](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-codelab/finished_code/src/test/java/com/example/android/kotlincoroutines/main/utils/MainCoroutineScopeRule.kt):

> MainCoroutineRule installs a TestCoroutineDispatcher for Disptachers.Main. Since it extends TestCoroutineScope, you can directly launch coroutines on the MainCoroutineRule as a [CoroutineScope]...

Defenition of [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html):

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion. This function should not be used from a coroutine. It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests. ...

In terms of definition, `runBlocking` is used for the sole purpose of synchronous execution in coroutines. It is not only used in tests but also used in UI management, Data Management, and several other areas in Android Development.

Whereas `runBlocking` is used more generally, `MainCoroutineRule` is used only in tests and it has the same synchronous execution behavior found in `runBlocking`. However, `MainCoroutineRule` has more specialized testing features not found in `runBlocking` such as control flow management. In addition, using `MainCoroutineRule` will significantly make your testing code cleaner.

In a much more detailed manner, MainCoroutineRule is directly related to JUnit Rule. If you have used JUnit before, you might remember filling out `@Before @After` to provide a testing environment for the test cases. If you have multiple test cases, you would eventually have to write multiple `@Before @After` to provide multiple testing environments, which could possibly lead to redundant boilerplate code. Now, this is where `MainCoroutineRule` shines! With `MainCoroutineRule` you can declare a testing environment once and reuse them for multiple test cases.

Compare two sample codes below:

Test case without using `MainCoroutineRule`

```
  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    class MyViewModelTest {
        private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

        @Before
        fun setup() {
            Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        }

        @After
        fun tearDown() {
            
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
         
            testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        }

        @Test
        fun testSomething() = runBlockingTest {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Test case using `MainCoroutineRule`

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(
    val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun MainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest(block: suspend () -> Unit) =
    this.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        block()
}
```

How convenient? This shows that Google actually cares for developers.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Amazing explanation, Thank you!

Comment: Migrate to the new Kotlin Test API: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md ;;;;;; https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140173/421467