# The TestScope advanced example of usage in tests with coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Could someone provide an advanced example of using the new `TestScope` and `TestScope.launch` while testing with coroutines?

It seems like in the new `kotlinx.coroutines.test` release they've added somewhat called `TestScope` to the library. Also, they've deprecated the old `TestCoroutineDispatcher` and told to use `TestScope.runTests` instead, however, they didn't add much documentation on how to use it. Everything I could find is [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test#accessing-the-test-coroutine-scope).

Can anyone provide me with some extra examples of usage in different scenarios?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. `TestScope` is just a replacement for `TestCoroutineScope`. It is provided as `this` by the top level `runTest`, just like `runBlocking` gives you a scope as well. So using `runtest { ... }` and nesting `launch` inside is effectively running coroutines in the test scope. Do you want examples of using the nested `TestScope.runTest`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could also fix this problem with @Joffrey mentioned at the comment.
You only need to use `runTest { }` to use coroutine scope at the test code. By using `runTest { }` you can use `TestScope` inside the block with `this`.

In my case, there was a flow function at the viewModel something like this. It was running inside the `viewModelScope`.

```kotlin
    fun getFriendDataWithFlow() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.loadFriendsWithFlow()
            ...
        }
     }
```

And I should test this at my test code, and I used it like this.

```kotlin
   @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
   @Before
   fun setup() {
       Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())
   }

   @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
   @Test
   fun temp() {
        runTest {
            viewModel.getFriendDataWithFlow()
        }
   }
```

All I did was add `runTest { }` block, and add coroutine code inside the block. And it worked for me.
My test coroutine dependency was `"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.0-RC"`.

Comment: I used `UnconfinedTestDispatcher()` instead to ensure all coroutines were dispatched immediately, which was the behavior I had written my tests for before the migration.